# Sencha show / hide element

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs

I have a simple form, and I work with a button that has a handler to get the submit. When the user clicks that button, I want to show a 'DIV'-element.

How is it possible to show / hide a specific element in Sencha?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show a component:

```
Ext.getCmp('YourDivID').show();
```

To hide a component:

```
Ext.getCmp('YourDivID').hide();
```

Before this, you have to of course create a component with YourDivID.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Helped me solve my problem. But can you also tell me how can i change the text on the button after clicking on it?

Comment: probably something like setText or setHtml, check the component documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component

Answer (score 2):

You have to use getCmp in order to select an element,

but you have to use `Ext.select()` in order to select an HTML element like divs.

Example usage:

```
Ext.select("#yourdiv").hide();
```